# Added java debugging which is not causing my java program to throw errors

Tags: java

I have the following simple Java program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    
    double rad;  
    double area;  
 
    System.out.print("radius #: "); 
    rad = input.nextDouble(); 
    System.err.println(rad);

    area = rad * rad * 3.14159; 
 
    System.out.println("Radius "  
     + rad + " is " + area); 

     input.close();
 } 
}
```

It was running great, but I wanted to practice debugging, so I added this line:

```
System.err.println(rad);
```

And it now gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
        at ComputeArea.main(ComputeArea.java:20)
```

What could I be doing wrong?

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried removing `input.close()`? Also, `System.err` isn't for debugging. Breakpoints in your IDE are.

Comment: @OneCricketeer No but it was working fine with input.close().  is there something wrong with input.close?  Also I am using Visual Studio Code by the Micro Soft.  thanks!

Comment: This error would happen if you enter a radius that can't be parsed as a double. So, I think it's not a change to the code causing the error, but a change to the input provided. What are you typing as the radius?

Comment: Java debugger works with the Java extension in Vscode just fine https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging